# Export large amount of data?

Tags: export, phpexcel

I'm trying to export large amount of data (~90000rows * 17columns) to excel file. However, after executing the script, no file is created at the location which I had specified.

I had tried

```
$cacheSettings = array( 'memoryCacheSize' => '64MB');
```

and

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '64M');
```

but none of these helps.

However, I manage to get the file created by reducing the number of columns.

I understand there are existing topic related to this question and I have gone through these topic but still couldn't find any solution to my problem.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried increasing the memory limit above 64MB? It seems to me that holding 90000 rows x 17 cols might need well above 512MB in phpexcel.

Comment: Tried it but nothing has change. Does it have a max value or I have to define a value for each report I try to export, because I have number of report needs to generate and all those report different in term of data size from each other.

Comment: That setting operates at  a script level, so it will alter php memory consumption for that script, that execution thread and only until it completes its execution.  Try to check php error logs to see if there's any trace of the script failing due to memory allocation or execution time.

Comment: So which cell caching method are you actually using (I'd guess cache_to_phpTemp).... you show code to configure cache settings, but no code for actually enabling any of the cache methods?

Comment: Did you miss something like: 
`PHPExcel_Settings::setCacheStorageMethod(PHPExcel_CachedObjectStorageFactory::cache_to_phpTemp);`

Answer (score 1):

Reading issues with packages using PHPExcel, it seems the best option is loading data in smaller chunks and appending to the same sheet.

[Further reading on one of the issues](https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel/issues/466)

Update may 2017:

If you are using [Laravel Excel](https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel), their 3.0 version is out with huge performance improvements. If a PHP 7.0 requirement is not a problem, it might be worth a look at.